# How can I create bind a list of elements as a group without ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to learn Angular but hit a small blocker. My markup has a list of DIVs which when clicked get toggled (a new class). This is a static list of options and I would like to avoid the `ng-repeat` directive.

```
<div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="item" id="germany">Germany</div>
    <div class="item" id="poland">Poland</div>
    <div class="item" id="sweden">Sweden</div>
    <div class="item" id="japan">Japan</div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="selected = []">Reset</button>
</div>
```

I would like to bind it to an array of selections. When clicked, the item's id should be added to the array and when unselected, it should be removed. The existence of the item's id in the selection array defines whether it should have the "active" class.

Below is how I've done it in Angular but this means that I cannot use my static list of DIVs but use the ng-repeat with the JSON. I've toyed around with this and got it correctly bound to the `selected` array. Clicking the button correctly resets the active class showing that the binding works.

Can I still accomplish this without going down the JSON + ng-repeat way? An example pointing me to this would be nice. Thank you

Here's the CSS:

```
.item {
    border-color: #ddd;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #444;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    margin: -1px;
    padding: 16px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.item.active {
    border-color: #ccc;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
```

Here's the JS:

```
var SampleApp;
(function (SampleApp) {

    var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.selected = [];

        $scope.clicked = function (member) {
            var index = $scope.selected.indexOf(member.name);
            if (index > -1) {
                $scope.selected.splice(index, 1);
                member.selected = false;
            } else {
                $scope.selected.push(member.name);
                member.selected = true;
            }
            console.log($scope.selected);
        }
        $scope.items = [{
            name: "item1"
        }, {
            name: "item2"
        }, {
            name: "item3"
        }, {
            name: "item4"
        }, {
            name: "item5"
        }];
    });

})(SampleApp || (SampleApp = {}));
```

Here's the markup:

```
<div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="clicked(item)" ng-class="{ active: selected.indexOf(item.name) !== -1 }" id="item.name">{{ item.name }}</div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="selected = []">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="item" id="germany" 
     ng-click="toggle('germany')" 
     ng-class="{ active: selected.indexOf('germany') >= 0 }">Germany</div>
```

and repeat the same pattern for the other countries.

In the controller:

```
$scope.toggle = function(country) {
    var index = $scope.selected.indexOf(country);
    if (index >= 0) {
        $scope.selected.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        $scope.selected.push(country);
    }
};
```

Not sure why you want to avoid ng-repeat though. Using it would avoid repeating the same code again and again in the view, and thus reduce the risk of introducing a bug.